# Hiding rows and sections on the basis of json obtained in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I have a viewcontroller,(say ViewcontrollerA).It has tableView and tableViewCells on it.

The tableView has three sections(section0,section1,section2).

1. Section0 has two rows,

   2.section1 has 9rows and

   3.section2 has 2 rows.

**I have a json as follows:**

```
  {"Error": null,
        "isModifiable":1,
        "Check":1,
        "Data": [{
                  "section": 1,
                  "row": 2
                  }, {
                  "section": 1,
                  "row": 3
                  }, {
                  "section": 1,
                  "row": 5
                  }, {
                  "section": 0,
                  "row": 1
                  }, {
                  "section": 2,
                  "row": 0
                  }]}
```

Here,in this json section and rows to be hdden are given.But I am able to access the array `[object at indexpath:0]` only.

But,actually I want to acess all the dictionary in array together.Following is the code I ahve used.Kindly review and suggest the corrections to be done.

Thanks in advance!

**here my code:**

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSDictionary * values=[self getTheRowsAndSectionDetailsFromJson];
        NSArray *tasks=[values objectForKey:@"Data"];
        NSDictionary* taskDic=[tasks objectAtIndex:0];
        NSInteger  rows=[[taskDic valueForKey:@"row"]intValue];
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)rows);
        NSInteger  section=[[taskDic valueForKey:@"section"]intValue];
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)section);


        if([[values objectForKey:@"isModifiable"]boolValue])
        {
            if((indexPath.row==rows
                )&&indexPath.section==section)
            {
                return 0.0;
            }
            else

                return 39.6;
        }
        else
            return 39.6;

    }

    -(NSDictionary*)getTheRowsAndSectionDetailsFromJson
    {
        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"json"];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSLog(@%@",dict);
        return dict;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(section == %@)",@(indexPath.section)];
NSArray *filteredArray = [[dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] valueForKeyPath:@"row"];
if([filteredArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:@(indexPath.row)]]){
    return 0.0;
}
```